Find the quotient of $L_1$ and $L_2$.
We want to find the quotient of languages $L_1$ and $L_2$.
My question is what happens when the length of a word in $L_2$ is greater than the length of the word in $L_1$, for instance:
$abc$ and $cc$.
And here is another question which is like above and a little different.
We have two languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ as the following:
$L_1 = \{00, 01, 10\}$
$L_2 = \{001, 110, 111\}$
I think the $L_1 / L_2$ is the set containing the empty word. Is this correct?
Here is the link to the definition of the quotient of formal languages.

What do you mean by quotient? Like division?

Yes, In formal languages we have right and left quotient

Just to be sure, could you give us your definition of the quotient.

Here is the link to the definition of the quotient of formal languages: quotient

Your intuition is incorrect. By definition,
$$
  L_1/L_2 = \bigl\{u \in \{0,1\}^* \mid \text{there exists $v \in L_2$ such that $uv \in L_1 \bigr\}$}
$$
Now, since $L_1 = \{00, 01, 10\}$ and $L_2 = \{001, 110, 111\}$, there is no word $u$ such $uv \in L_1$ for some $v \in L_2$. Consequently $L_1/L_2 = \emptyset$.

J.-E Pin, The empty word is not in $L_1$ and $L_2$. But by definition  $u \in $ {0, 1}*. And because of that I thought that the empty word could be one the answers. what do you think?

No. If $u = \varepsilon$, there is no word $v$ of $L_2$ such that $uv \in L_1$.
